# Single Line separated records in SQL SERVER Query result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, csv

I had a query that returned multiple rows from a table. Then I converted that query to this one:

```
;with mycte as 
(select s.FirstName + ' ' + s.LastName as Name from ClientStaff cs 
left outer join Staff s on s.Id = cs.StaffId 
left outer join GeneralStatus gs on gs.Id = s.StatusId
 where cs.ClientId = @clientId and gs.Name = 'Active')

 select @staff = (select distinct staff = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE((select Name AS [data()] FROM mycte a 
 order by a.Name for xml path),'</row><row>',', '),'</row>',''),'<row>','') from mycte b)
```

It returns those rows in a single comma-separated row.
Now I don't want comma-separated values, instead I want single-line-separated values.
Can anyone tell me if it is possible or not?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare @staff varchar(max)

;with mycte as 
(
    select distinct s.FirstName + ' ' + s.LastName as Name 
    from ClientStaff cs 
        left outer join Staff s on 
            s.Id = cs.StaffId 
        left outer join GeneralStatus gs on 
        gs.Id = s.StatusId
    where cs.ClientId = @clientId and gs.Name = 'Active'
)
select @staff = isnull(@staff + char(13), '') + Name
from mycte b

print @staff
```

Comment: It's still comma-separated. I need line-separation.

Comment: @asma - you need to use char(13). Updated the answer.

Comment: +1, but depending on whether the output is meant to be processed additionally after consuming or used directly for displaying, it might be better to use `CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)` as the delimiter.

Comment: @Andriy: I just need to display the data.